# Is something wrong with the way the ads are being chosen? All I see are hot questions

Tags: support, status-norepro, community, advertising

In the Community ad section on the homepage there is a section for Community ads, hot questions and a few SE ads:

[image]

However I noticed that pretty much all I see are hot questions. While I *am* interested in the hot questions, I'd prefer it if they weren't shown as much (after all, a list of them is displayed right below the ad). I went a whole 12 reloads without seeing a community ad. The second time I tested I went 30 reloads without seeing a community ad and eventually gave up.

Is this really the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - when you said "hot questions" I was looking at the area below the "graphical representation", which has the title "hot questions".

Comment: @guntbert Right, which is why I have a problem with the hot questions showing as an ad. If I want to see a hot question, I'll look in the list ;P

Comment: I heartily agree - for me it is not really an issue - I seldom look at the right side anyway - thats where most websites place their ads and my eyes/brain combination seems to avoid them - if not somebody (I believe it was you) had told me where to look for "related questions" I wouldn't have seen them till now :-))

Comment: Heh, you picked the wrong example ad, that's a very good ad to show today. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a mix of various ads - hot questions, Area 51 proposals, community ads, etc. within about 10 reloads. (I forgot to count, but it just took me a few seconds to go through this.)

Comment: I just tried reloading and changing pages, to get 10 ads, and at least 7 were hot questions off other sites, 1 Area 51 proposal, and 2 community ads...

Comment: Well it certainly seems to be *better* now, but I'm still seeing way more hot questions than I'd like, but I guess now it is just personal preference. Maybe something changed recently.